# Is there any way to block websites without Root access

Tags: browser

I am searching for a way to block websites without having root access.
Is there any way to do it?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sup>Summed-up solution from above comments:</sup>

You can use a filtering proxy like e.g. [FilterProxy](http://www.appbrain.com/app/FilterProxy/KRIS.android.FilterProxy), which lets you define what URLs should be blocked. To prevent other users from simply disabling the proxy then, you could protect it using an app locker like e.g. [App Lock](http://www.appbrain.com/app/App-Lock/com.domobile.applock).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to point out another possible solution, since I had some inconveniences with FilterProxy. I now use [DNS 66](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.jak_linux.dns66/), which, conveniently, can also block ads, etc.

I just had to create my own hosts file myhosts.txt somewhere on my phone with the following entries:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

0.0.0.0 www.badwebsite1.com
0.0.0.0 www.badwebsite2.com
```

You can install DNS 66 via F-Droid. And of course you can use an app locker to protect it, as described in the post by Izzy.